# How do get a script to automatically run before saving a file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I want Xcode to run a particular script before any file is saved.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, but if you can detail why you need this, maybe other solutions could be applicable.

Comment: related: [How do I run a script every time I save a file in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189029/how-do-i-run-a-script-every-time-i-save-a-file-in-linux)

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't.

Comment: If you believe anyone, believe cdespinosa. He works on XCode.

Comment: If @cdespinosa is still working on  XCode...  ... why is this still a No answer.    Rinkydink 2nd class IDE ... smh.  Before anyone rushes to defend XCode, how many times did you have to restart / clear derived data this week?