# How do I run a script every time I save a file in Linux?

Tags: linux

How do I run a script every time I save a file in Linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linux has a subsystem call [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) which can cause filesystems to report changes in the filesystem to applications.

Your linux system probably has a package called `incron` which makes using `inotify` very easy. (Or search your available packages for any package whose description contains the word 'inotify').

Setting up `incron` is very much like setting up `cron`, except whereas `cron` executes a script at a specified time and date, `incron` executes a script whenever a specified file or directory changes.

PS. On Ubuntu (for example), `incron` is [this package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/incron) and is installed with

```
sudo apt-get install incron
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and ended up writing a python script to do it for me.

https://github.com/bawigga/spy

usage:

```
$ ./spy myscript.py
... your script output ...

$ ./spy --help
Usage: spy [OPTIONS] [WATCH]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c, --clear           clear the screen after each execution
  -e COMMAND, --exec=COMMAND
                        path to the program to execute
  -i INTERVAL, --interval=INTERVAL
                        (in seconds) set the time interval to check for file
                        modifications
```